# Get records associated to null value if no match is found using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a requirement where coupons are associated to each state. Below is the table structure

```
╔═════════╦═══════╗
║ Coupon  ║ State ║
╠═════════╬═══════╣
║ Coupon1 ║ CA    ║
║ Coupon2 ║ CA    ║
║ Coupon3 ║ NULL  ║
╚═════════╩═══════╝
```

If no coupons are found for the state the default coupon will be shown to the users.How can i change the below lambda expression in such a way to achieve the result. For instance if the passed in state is "CA" the below expression is returning both values and getting the first set instead of getting the accurate result (get coupons associated to CA since this is already found)

```
var loggedinUserCoupons = loggedinUser.Coupons.Where(x => x.StateId == loggedinUsers.StateID || x.StateId == null).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Use [the `DefaultIfEmpty` action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) function lets you provide a fallback if your main query returns no results:

```
var fallback = loggedinUser.Coupons
                           .Where(x => x.StateId == null)
                           .First();
var loggedinUserCoupons = loggedinUser.Coupons
                                      .Where(x => x.StateId == loggedinUsers.StateID)
                                      .DefaultIfEmpty(fallback);
```

If it's important to enumerate the source only once, you can use this:

```
IEnumerable<T> WhereWithDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                   Predicate<T> primaryCondition,
                                   Predicate<T> fallbackCondition)
{
    var fallback = new List<T>();
    bool foundPrimary = false;
    foreach( T t in source ) {
        if (primaryCondition(t)) { foundPrimary = true; fallback.Clear(); yield return t; }
        else if (!foundPrimary && fallbackCondition(t)) { fallback.Add(t); }
    }
    if (foundPrimary) yield break;
    foreach (T t in fallback) yield return t;
}

var loggedinUserCoupons = loggedinUser.Coupons
                                      .WhereWithDefault(x => x.StateId == loggedinUsers.StateID, x => x.StateId == null);
```

But note that the first approach is better for LINQ-to-SQL, because the database only has to return objects that match the two IDs and not the whole table.

Comment: Right, this avoids the `if` check but still does two iterations of the `loggedinUser.Coupons` which I mentioned to the OP is the best that can be done in this particular case as I cannot think of a solution that will enumerate the source only once.

Comment: @Aominè: Please note that the first line is needed only once no matter how many lookups are done.

Comment: @Aominè: I'll add a version that enumerates the source only once, however.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this in two steps.

First, attempt to find all the `Coupon`'s that have their state id as say `CA` like so:

```
var loggedinUserCoupons = 
            loggedinUser.Coupons
                        .Where(x => x.StateId == loggedinUsers.StateID)
                        .ToList();
```

if no elements where found then we can get the default `Coupon` you've provided like so:

```
if(loggedinUserCoupons.Count == 0)
   loggedinUserCoupons = new List<Coupon>() {
                         loggedinUser.Coupons
                                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StateId == null) };
```

If there will always be a default `Coupon` at the end of the list then you can simply do:

```
 if(loggedinUserCoupons.Count == 0)
       loggedinUserCoupons = new List<Coupon>() {
                             loggedinUser.Coupons
                                         .Last() };
```

Comment: The whole point of `FirstOrDefault` is that you don't have to write the `if` yourself.

Comment: @Aominè - I know i would be able to achieve this if i wrote a conditional statement. How can i get the result in a single lambda expression/statement?

Comment: @BenVoigt if we don't check for `if(loggedinUserCoupons.Count == 0)` then we will always overwrite the previous result even if there were elements in it. or I'm I missing misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Yoda _"How can i get the result in a single lambda expression/statement?"_ In this particular case, you can't it, unfortunately.

Comment: @Aominè: It's hard to prove a negative.... really hard when there actually is an answer.